# How to select last record in a LINQ GroupBy clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following simple table with *ID*, *ContactId* and *Comment*.

[image]

I want to select records and `GroupBy contactId`. I used this `LINQ` extension method statement:

```
Mains.GroupBy(l => l.ContactID)
 .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
 .ToList()
```

It returns record `1` and `4`. How can I use `LINQ` to get the `ContactID` with the highest `ID`? (i.e. return `3` and `6`)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can order you items

```
Mains.GroupBy(l => l.ContactID)
.Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(c=>c.ID).FirstOrDefault()) 
.ToList()
```

Comment: Despite this query will return correct data, it results in compilation into K+1 SQL statements, where K is number of keys (use LINQpad to see it).
I faced same problem today and solved it this way:
`
var lastCommentIDs = Mains.GroupBy(k => k.ContactID, e => e.ID, (k, e) => new { k, lastID = e.Max(x => x)});
var result = lastCommentIDs.Join(Mains, o => o.lastID, i => i.ID, (o, i) => new { ContactID = o.k, LastComment = i.Comment).ToList();
`

Comment: Hi, @Dmitrij. Thanks for feedback. Linqpad is using Linq to SQL, did you tried Linq to entities with this?

Comment: Hi, @tym32167. yes, I had an attempt to jump into EF, not sure wha exactly was wrong, but EF produced ugliest and absolutely inefficient SQL queries out of LINQ statements. Probably I did something wrong, not sure but the fact is: LINQ2SQL produces more predictable queries than EF. (at least I understand what will happen when I'm executing paticular query using LINQ2SQL)

Answer (score 8):

Use [`OrderByDescending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby(v=vs.110).aspx) on the items in the group:

```
Mains.GroupBy(l => l.ContactID)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(l => l.ID).First())
    .ToList();
```

Also, there is no need for `FirstOrDefault` when selecting an item from the group; a group will always have at least one item so you can use `First()` safely.

Comment: A shorter version: `g => g.OrderBy(l => l.ID).Last()` :)

Answer (score 6):

**Perhaps** selecting with `Max` instead of `OrderByDescending` could result into improving of performance (I'm not sure how it's made inside so it needs to be tested):

```
var grouped = Mains.GroupBy(l => l.ContactID);
var ids = grouped.Select(g => g.Max(x => x.Id));
var result = grouped.Where(g => ids.Contains(g.Id));
```

As I assume it could result into a query that will take `MAX` and then do `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id IN ({max ids here})` which could be significantly faster than `OrderByDescending`.

Feel free to correct me if I'm not right.

Comment: fater than OrderBy

Comment: Should that last line be...?  var result = Mains.Where(g => ids.Contains(g.Id));

Answer (score 3):

OrderByDescending

```
Mains.GroupBy(l => l.ContactID)
.Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(c=>c.ID).FirstOrDefault()) 
.ToList()
```

is your best solution

It orders by the highest ID descending, which is pretty obvious from the name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MoreLinq like this for a shorter solution:

```
Main.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).DistinctBy(l => l.ContactID).ToList();
```